# MS ACCESS / SQL: Select maximum count per person, per variable

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access, I've joined two tables, one table is a list of sales and the city they took place (Sales), and another is a table of persons and the sales their participated in (SalePersons).

When joining the two tables, you can see that the combined table details many sales per person across many cities. My goal is obtain the most-frequented city for sales per each person.

For example, Customer 1 might have 2 sales in Baltimore, 1 sale in New York, and 3 Washington; customer 2 might have 3 sales in Washington, 4 sale in Wichita, and 1 sale in New York. The table needs to have only "Washington" listed for Customer 1, and only "Wichita" listed for Customer 2. If there's a tie, I'd like to list all the tied cities.

So far, I only have the initial join working.

```
SELECT SalePersons.PersonID, Count(Sales.SaleNum) AS CountOfSaleNum, Sales.CITY
FROM Sales INNER JOIN SalePersons ON Sales.SaleNum = SalePersons.SaleNum
GROUP BY SalePersons.PersonID, Sales.CITY;
```

But, as you might guess, this join will only give me the count of sales per city, per person *across all cities*. I need to retrieve only the 1 most-frequented city person.

I thought I could make this a subquery and wrap all this all under a Select MAX(CountOfSaleNum) clause, but that didn't work. I still have much to learn.

Thank you in advance! I don't know what I'd do without this site sometimes.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT sp.*
FROM (SELECT sp.PersonID, COUNT(*) AS CountOfSaleNum, s.CITY,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sp.PersonID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Sales s INNER JOIN
           SalePersons sp
           ON s.SaleNum = sp.SaleNum
      GROUP BY sp.PersonID, s.CITY
     ) sp
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

In MS Access, you are stuck with a more complicated query:

```
SELECT sp.PersonID, COUNT(*) AS CountOfSaleNum, s.CITY
FROM Sales as s INNER JOIN
     SalePersons as sp
     ON s.SaleNum = sp.SaleNum
GROUP BY sp.PersonID, s.CITY
HAVING s.City = (SELECT TOP 1 s2.City
                 FROM Sales as s2 INNER JOIN
                      SalePersons as sp2
                      ON s2.SaleNum = sp2.SaleNum
                 WHERE sp2.PersonID = sp.PersonId
                 GROUP BY sp2.PersonId, s2.City
                 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, s2.City
                );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I should've mentioned I'm using MS Access. When I run this code, I'm getting a syntax error for a missing operator in  the ROW_NUMBER() line. I'm not that familiar with window functions, so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks! The only thing is that my version of Access didn't like a the parenthesis in TOP (1) code, but this works great.